# How to remove all products that are not in any category from catalog search result magento

Tags: magento

Today I'm trying to remove all product that are not in any category from catalog search result collection.

in mage\catalog\model\resource\product\collection.php  I tried to add list of all categories IDs in search query in function _applyProductLimitations():

```
if (!isset($filters['category_ids'])) {
         $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()
            ->quoteInto('cat_index.category_id=?', $filters['category_id']);
        if (isset($filters['category_is_anchor'])) {
            $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()
                ->quoteInto('cat_index.is_parent=?', $filters['category_is_anchor']);
        }
    } else {

        $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()->quoteInto('cat_index.category_id IN(' . implode(',', $filters['category_ids']) . ')', "");
        // $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()->quoteInto('cat_index.category_id = 102');
        // $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()->quoteInto('count(cat_index.category_id) > 0 "" ');
    }
```

and add filter in catalofsearch layer filter model:

```
->addCategoriesFilter($rootCategory->getAllChildren(true))
```

Query string:

```
SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`rakuten_top_style`, `e`.`rakuten_top_style_value`, `e`.`gift_type`, `e`.`gift_value`, `e`.`gift_price`, `e`.`gift_from`, `e`.`gift_to`, `e`.`gift_dropdown`, `e`.`gift_price_type`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `tmp_table`.`relevance`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.category_id IN(2,102,100,127,32,90,92,94,96,104,84,98,129,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,125,130,131,132,133,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,33,101,128,35,36,34,43,91,93,95,45,57,63,73,77,107,108,111,124,53,54,55,56,71,72,76,110,97,83,109,78,81,82,85,86,87,88,99) LEFT JOIN `searchindex_result_mage_catalog_product` AS `tmp_table` ON (tmp_table.product_id=e.entity_id) INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 WHERE (tmp_table.id IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY `relevance` desc
```

But the search result is still got products that are not belong to any category, please give me some advice how to do it, thank you so much!

Comment: where is your `addCategoriesFilter` function?

Comment: I added in product\collection.php : public function addCategoriesFilter($categories)
    {
        $this->_productLimitationFilters['category_ids'] = $categories;

        if ($this->getStoreId() == Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID) {
            $this->_applyZeroStoreProductLimitations();
        } else {
            $this->_applyProductLimitations();
        }

        return $this;
    }